# How to apply the image fade effect in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, effects, fade

I am trying to apply the fade effect for images in as3 (not in flash or flex), but examples contain with flash or flex only I want to pure action script example for image fade effect. Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "examples contain with flash or flex "

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like using the free [TweenMax Library](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/), something like:

```
TweenLite.to(yourImage_mc, 1, {alpha:0});
```

Or you can do the built in Tween stuff:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
var t:Tween = new Tween(yourImage_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 1, 0, 3, true);
```

[fl.transitions.Tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#Tween%28%29)

I strongly suggest you read the docs for both and decide for yourself.

Comment: This is flash professional (.fla file)example.i want to create a action-script project in adobe flash builder 4.i cannot import tween effect in adobe flash builder 4.

Comment: In Flash Builder's Project properties make sure to add an Actiosncript build path with a source path to the TweenMax library (after downloading and unzipping of course). Or even copy the library into your project (less proper but should work). There shouldn't be too many issues since it is all Actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

TransitionManager.start(img1_mc, {type:Fade, direction:Transition.IN, duration:9, easing:Strong.easeOut});
```